# Why is there a tight polling loop on register rax in libc nanosleep?

Tags: linux, x86, system-calls

The disassembly of nanosleep in libc-2.7.so on 64-bit Linux looks like this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000bd460 <__nanosleep>:
    cmpl   $0x0,__libc_multiple_threads
    jne    10

00000000000bd469 <__nanosleep_nocancel>:
    mov    $0x23,%eax
    syscal
10: cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
    jae    40
    retq
    sub    $0x8,%rsp
    callq  __libc_enable_asynccancel
    mov    %rax,(%rsp)
    mov    $0x23,%eax
    syscal
    mov    (%rsp),%rdi
    mov    %rax,%rdx
    callq  __libc_disable_asynccancel
    mov    %rdx,%rax
    add    $0x8,%rsp
40: cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
    jae    40
    retq
    mov    _DYNAMIC+0x2e0,%rcx
    neg    %eax
    mov    %eax,%fs:(%rcx)
    or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
    retq
```

Near the bottom of this assembly code, there is this polling loop:

```
40: cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
    jae    40
```

How would the value of `rax` change while this loop is executing? Wouldn't it either loop forever or not at all? What is this loop meant to accomplish?

I suspect this is related to the `syscall` instruction since the return value of `syscall` is put into register `rax`, but I'm not sure how this is related exactly. The way the code is written makes it *look* like `syscall` doesn't block and the value in `rax` changes spontaneously but that doesn't seem right.

I'm interested to know what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see these spin loops.

Here's what I get from `objdump -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, with what you show as loops highlighted with `**` and the address they jump to with `->`.

```
00000000000c0f10 <__nanosleep>:
   c0f10:       83 3d 5d 31 30 00 00    cmpl   $0x0,0x30315d(%rip)        # 3c4074 <argp_program_version_hook+0x1cc>
   c0f17:       75 10                   jne    c0f29 <__nanosleep+0x19>
   c0f19:       b8 23 00 00 00          mov    $0x23,%eax
   c0f1e:       0f 05                   syscall 
   c0f20:       48 3d 01 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
** c0f26:       73 31                   jae    c0f59 <__nanosleep+0x49>
   c0f28:       c3                      retq   
   c0f29:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   c0f2d:       e8 3e 72 04 00          callq  108170 <pthread_setcanceltype+0x80>
   c0f32:       48 89 04 24             mov    %rax,(%rsp)
   c0f36:       b8 23 00 00 00          mov    $0x23,%eax
   c0f3b:       0f 05                   syscall 
   c0f3d:       48 8b 3c 24             mov    (%rsp),%rdi
   c0f41:       48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
   c0f44:       e8 87 72 04 00          callq  1081d0 <pthread_setcanceltype+0xe0>
   c0f49:       48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
   c0f4c:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
   c0f50:       48 3d 01 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
** c0f56:       73 01                   jae    c0f59 <__nanosleep+0x49>
   c0f58:       c3                      retq   
-> c0f59:       48 8b 0d 08 cf 2f 00    mov    0x2fcf08(%rip),%rcx        # 3bde68 <_IO_file_jumps+0x7c8>
   c0f60:       f7 d8                   neg    %eax
   c0f62:       64 89 01                mov    %eax,%fs:(%rcx)
   c0f65:       48 83 c8 ff             or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
   c0f69:       c3                      retq   
   c0f6a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

The rest of the code is similar. Maybe it's an issue with the disassembly?

Comment: It looks like you're right! `objdump -d` reports something similar to what you show. The disassembler in `perf` put the labels on the wrong instructions. In both cases, it put the label on the instruction with an address that is 9 bytes lower than the actual address contained in the jump. It looks like it rounded down the `+0x49` jump to `+0x40`. Likewise for the `+0x19` jump.